# Special relativity "paradox" and inertial frames

Tags: special-relativity

I have not studied Special relativity, so bare with me.

Though experiment 1:

in my frame of reference there is a moving charge creating a magnetic field. consider charge A, accelerates from stationary such that it matches the velocity of the charge already moving.

in my frame of reference, there is a magnetic field, and a moving charge, thus charge A experiences a magnetic force,

From charge A's perspective, it is not moving nor is there a magnetic field, thus no magnetic force, from what I have heard about SR is that this is resolved via length contraction in the charge A's reference frame , causing a different electric field that has the  the same effect as the previous magneticnfield

I am also told that because charge A is accelerating, it is  THIS frame of reference that gets length contracted, instead of the observer frame ( same resolution as the twin paradox, as each twin says eachothers length contract)

Scenario 2,

Let's say in my frame of reference there is a stationary charge, and charge A is stationary,

In this frame of reference there is no magnetic field and thus the only force on charge A is the STANDARD electric field (Coulombs law).

this time, the OBSERVER accelerates, to some velocity. in this frame of reference charge A should experience a magnetic force.

But in charge A's perspective, no lengthccontraction has occurred since it was not the one accelerating and thus it should still only feel the coulomb force,

Thus a paradox of 2 frames experiencing different force?

My first thought was that in the frame of reference of the accelerating observer, because his length contracts, This could somehow  negate the magnetic field produced in this frame ( but I'm pretty sure length contraction is the REASON the magnetic force exists in this frame)

In the 2 scenarios, they have an identicle end result in terms  of velocitie,But different forces?

What am I not understanding?

Comment: An uncharged observer accelerates away from two charges that are at rest with respect to one another and expects them to experience a magnetic force?

Comment: an uncharged observer accelerating would  see a force on charge A caused by the magnetic force

Comment: The need to learn Special Relativity before making up "paradoxes".